# Meteor Reactive Session: Not Working (Why?)

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm having trouble with reactive Sessions in Meteor.js.

Demo: [Meteor Pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/i4aeBBvYB8wiNAgpq/Blaze%20Test)

```
Template.rows.helpers({
  'rows': function () {
     return Session.get('rows'); // data set in Session
  }
});

Template.count.events({
  'click .mdl-radio__button': function (e) {
    // target represents a number of selected rows (1, 2, 5, or 10)
    var value = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    Session.set('limit', value);
  },
  'click #reset': function () {
    Session.set('limit', 0);
    Session.set('rows', null);
  },
  'click #run': function () {
    // should only get rows when run() is pressed
    Session.set('rows', currentItems);
  }
});
```

Users should be able to select a new number of collections to receive, controlled by the limit. However, I keep getting the following error:

`Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation`

Any ideas why? Can someone show me a working MeteorPad demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Apparently Session creates a string, so that `Session.set('limit', 1)` sets the limit to `"1"`. Of course, strings can be processed in a Mongo collection request.

The solution was using `{limit: parseInt(Session.get('limit')}`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble with your meteorpad. But your problem isn't `Session`. The problem is your usage of `Tracker.autorun`. You should read the [docs on that](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun).

You are assuming that `Tracker.autorun(getItems)` returns what `getItems` returns. That's not the case tough. You'll need to set `currentItems` inside the `autorun` (in your case `getItems`).

```
getItems = function () {
  if (Session.get('limit') > 0) {
    currentItems = Items
      .find({}, {limit: Session.get('limit')})
      .map(function (item, index) {
        item.index = index + 1;
        return item;
      });
  } else {
    currentItems = null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same error.The strange part is, if I call `Items.find({}, {limit: 10})` it works, but if just above I set `var limit = 10; Items.find({}, {limit: limit})` it fails. Any variable with the collection call causes it to fail. Any idea why?

Comment: @shmck That can't be the reason it fails. It must be the contents of `limit`.

Comment: Posted the solution above. I didn't know that Session stringifies numbers.